# Prove a property of solutions of Tricomi equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$G$ is a region contained in upper half plane of $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is, for every point $(x,y)$ in $G$  we have $y>0$.

If $u$ is a solution of the equation $yu_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, show that $u$ couldn't attain its maximum in interior of $G$, if $u$ is not a constant.

I have no idea. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is the strong maximum principle for elliptic pdes. Lawrence Evans's book "Partial Differential Equations" has a proof in chapter 6.  There are also many proofs of this online.

Comment: @user254433 Thanks..But now we haven't learnt what you mentioned and this problem appear in my homework...So could we solve this problem using some particular methods ?